# special price product collection working but loading speed is too slow ,I don't understand why the speed is so slow please help!

Tags: magento2, discount, magento2.3.5, special-price

```
<?php

namespace Product\Discount\Block;
use Magento\Catalog\Api\CategoryRepositoryInterface;

/*
use Magento\Catalog\Api\CategoryRepositoryInterface;
use Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\Context;
use Magento\Framework\Data\Helper\PostHelper;
use Magento\Catalog\Model\Layer\Resolver;
use Magento\Framework\Url\Helper\Data;
use Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\Collection;
use Magento\Framework\App\ResourceConnection;
*/
class Getproductspecialprice extends \Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ListProduct
{
    protected $_collection;

    protected $categoryRepository;

    protected $_resource;
   
   
    public function __construct(
    \Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\Context $context,
            \Magento\Framework\Data\Helper\PostHelper $postDataHelper,
            \Magento\Catalog\Model\Layer\Resolver $layerResolver,
            CategoryRepositoryInterface $categoryRepository,
            \Magento\Framework\Url\Helper\Data $urlHelper,
            \Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\Collection $collection,
            \Magento\Framework\App\ResourceConnection $resource,
            array $data = []
    ) {
        $this->categoryRepository = $categoryRepository;
        $this->_collection = $collection;
        $this->_resource = $resource;

        parent::__construct($context, $postDataHelper, $layerResolver, $categoryRepository, $urlHelper, $data);
    }

    public function getproductcollection()
    {
       
       
         $page=($this->getRequest()->getParam('p'))? $this->getRequest()->getParam('p') : 1;
         $pageSize=($this->getRequest()->getParam('limit'))? $this->getRequest()->getParam('limit') : 8;

        $category_id = $this->getRequest()->getParam('cid'); // pass your category id
        $objectManager =  \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();        
        $categoryFactory = $objectManager->get('\Magento\Catalog\Model\CategoryFactory');
        $allChildrenCategoryIdsArr=[];
        $setTitle='';
        if($category_id==66505){
            $category = $categoryFactory->create()->load(66462);
            $allChildrenCategoryIdsArr = $category->getAllChildren(true);
            
        }
        elseif($category_id==66506){
            $category = $categoryFactory->create()->load(66466);
            $allChildrenCategoryIdsArr = $category->getAllChildren(true);
            //$this->_setTitle='Men';
        }
        elseif($category_id==66507){
            $category1 = $categoryFactory->create()->load(66467);
            $allChildrenCategoryIdsArr1 = $category1->getAllChildren(true);
            
            $category2 = $categoryFactory->create()->load(66468);
            $allChildrenCategoryIdsArr2 = $category2->getAllChildren(true);
            
            $allChildrenCategoryIdsArr=array_merge($allChildrenCategoryIdsArr1,$allChildrenCategoryIdsArr2);        
            //$this->_setTitle='Kids';
        }
        else{
            $category1 = $categoryFactory->create()->load(66469);
            $allChildrenCategoryIdsArr1 = $category1->getAllChildren(true);
            
            $category2 = $categoryFactory->create()->load(66470);
            $allChildrenCategoryIdsArr2 = $category2->getAllChildren(true);
            
            $allChildrenCategoryIdsArr=array_merge($allChildrenCategoryIdsArr1,$allChildrenCategoryIdsArr2);        
            //$this->_setTitle='Baby';
        }       
        /*
        $collection = clone $this->_collection;
        $collection->clear()->getSelect()->reset(\Magento\Framework\DB\Select::WHERE)->reset(\Magento\Framework\DB\Select::ORDER)->reset(\Magento\Framework\DB\Select::LIMIT_COUNT)->reset(\Magento\Framework\DB\Select::LIMIT_OFFSET)->reset(\Magento\Framework\DB\Select::GROUP);
        */
        $collection = clone $this->_collection;
        $collection->clear()->getSelect()->reset(\Magento\Framework\DB\Select::WHERE)->reset(\Magento\Framework\DB\Select::ORDER)->reset(\Magento\Framework\DB\Select::LIMIT_COUNT)->reset(\Magento\Framework\DB\Select::LIMIT_OFFSET)->reset(\Magento\Framework\DB\Select::GROUP);

        $categorycollection = $allChildrenCategoryIdsArr;
        $today_date = date('Y-m-d');
        if (isset($categorycollection) && !empty($categorycollection))
        {
          
         
            $collection
                ->addMinimalPrice()
                ->addFinalPrice()
                ->addTaxPercents()
                ->addAttributeToSelect('*')
                ->addAttributeToFilter('special_price', ['neq' => ''])   
                ->addCategoriesFilter(['in' => $categorycollection])
                ->groupByAttribute('color')
                ->addAttributeToSort('entity_id','desc')    
                ->addAttributeToFilter('is_saleable', 1, 'left');
                
        }
        else
        {
            
             $collection
                ->addMinimalPrice()
                ->addFinalPrice()
                ->addTaxPercents()
                ->addAttributeToSelect('*')
                ->addAttributeToFilter('special_price', ['neq' => ''])   
                ->addAttributeToSort('entity_id','desc')
                ->groupByAttribute('color')
                ->addAttributeToFilter('is_saleable', 1, 'left');
        }
        
          //$collection->getSelect()->limit(3);
        
        $collection->setPageSize($pageSize);
        $collection->setCurPage($page);
        //$collection->setCurPage($page);
        //echo $collection->load(true);
        //exit;
        return $collection;
    }
    
protected function _prepareLayout()
{
    parent::_prepareLayout();
    $this->pageConfig->getTitle()->set(__('Discount Product'));


    if ($this->getproductcollection()) {
        $pager = $this->getLayout()->createBlock(
            'Magento\Theme\Block\Html\Pager',
            'product.discount.pager'
        )->setAvailableLimit(array(4=>4,8=>8))->setShowPerPage(True)->setCollection(
            $this->getproductcollection()
        );
        $this->setChild('pager', $pager);
        $this->getproductcollection()->load();
    }
    
    return $this;
}

public function getPagerHtml()
{
    
    return $this->getChildHtml('pager');
}

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here are some improvements you can do.

Try getting rid of `->addAttributeToSelect('*')`. Select only what you need. Adding all product attributes can be expensive.
You can use `->addAttributeToSelect($this->catalogConfig->getProductAttributes())` where  `$this->catalogConfig` is an instance of `\Magento\Catalog\Model\Config` that you can provide as a dependency in constructor.

Also, I have a feeling that you method `getproductcollection` gets called more than once and everything inside it gets executed multiple times.

You can solve this by using [memoization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memoization).

First of all remove this dependency from your constructor `\Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\Collection $collection` (but leave the `protected $_collection;` member)

And replace it with a collection factory
`\Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\CollectionFactory $collectionFactory,`.

Now make your `getproductcollection` method looks something like this

```
if ($this->_collection === null) {
    //your logic in here
    //but replace
    //$collection = clone $this->_collection;
        $collection->clear()->getSelect()->reset(\Magento\Framework\DB\Select::WHERE)->reset(\Magento\Framework\DB\Select::ORDER)->reset(\Magento\Framework\DB\Select::LIMIT_COUNT)->reset(\Magento\Framework\DB\Select::LIMIT_OFFSET)->reset(\Magento\Framework\DB\Select::GROUP);

    //with $collection = $this->collectionFactory->create();

    //and at the end
    $this->collection = $collection;
}
return $this->collection;
```

Comment: if there is plugin for this ,can u suggest ?